# ReferenceError: jurusan is not defined in Angular with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I'm new to this and trying AngularJS and NodeJS, I got stuck in this error.

I am trying to make a dynamic select option, I'm trying to echo a table from MySQL database using NodeJS and throw the data to Angular. I've tried a lot stuff to resolved this problem, but maybe I still don't really understand about angular, so I haven't resolve the problem yet.

I'm using nodeJS ver. 1.0.0, and AngularJS version 1.7.5. Here is my code:

controlAll.js

```
var http = require('http');
var qs = require('querystring');
var fs = require('fs');
var hbs = require('hbs');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var route = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var konek = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "mahasiswa",
});
konek.connect(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("udah konek");
});

route.set('view engine', 'hbs');
route.use(bodyParser.json());
route.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

route.get('/mahasiswa/add', function(req, res){
    res.render("formm");
});
route.get('/jurusan', function(req,res){
    konek.query("SELECT * FROM `jurusan`",function(err,jurusan)
    {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            jurusan:jurusan
        }));
    });
});
```

formm.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>tambah mahasiswa</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/asset/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="/asset/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="coba">
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action="/mahasiswa/add">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nama Mahasiswa</label>
                <input type="text" name="nama" placeholder="nama" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nomor Pokok Mahasiswa</label>
                <input type="text" name="npm" placeholder="npm" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div ng-controller="drpdn">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Jurusan</label>
                    <select name="id_jurusan" ng-model="jurusan" class="form-control">
                        <option disabled selected value>--Pilih Jurusan--</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="jur in jurusan" value="{{jur.id_jurusan}}">{{jur.namajurusan}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Program Studi</label>
                    <select name="id_prodi" class="form-control">
                        <option disabled selected value>--Pilih Program Studi--</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">simpan</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('coba',[]);
app.controller('drpdn', function($scope, $http){
       $http.get("/jurusan")  
       .then(function(response){
            $scope.jurusan = response.jurusan;
       });
  console.log($scope.jurusan);
});
</script>
```

My nodejs response, I put the array in another route:

[image: nodejs]

```
console.log($scope.jurusan)
```

[image]

And here is my error:

[image: my error]

Another error:

[image: error 2]

Comment: The error is clear enough, `$scope.jurusan = jurusan;` here jurusan is not defined anywhere in your code. Are you expecting `jurusan` to be some value coming from server?

Comment: i am expecting `jurusan` in angular will show data from `jurusan` in nodeJS @PalSingh

Comment: Angular (or frontend) is not aware of anything you have declared in NodeJS (or server), so you need to fetch data from server using $http and assign it to jurusan

Comment: so i have to declare route for fetching `jurusan` in nodeJS file?? @PalSingh

Comment: would you write your answer please @PalSingh

Answer (score 0):

Your controller (or make a service) should load `jurusan` data from your nodejs endpoint and then use it:

```
app.controller('drpdn', function($scope, $http){
    // Simple GET request example:
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/jurusan' // USE YOUR NODEJS ENDPOINT TO LOAD DATA
    }).then(function(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
        $scope.jurusan = response.data.jurusan;
    }, function(response) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
});
```

Comment: i've tried your answer, and the `<option>` is being repeat, but it doesn't show the text, it's just blank

Comment: do `$scope.jurusan = response.jurusan;`

Comment: Can you post the exact response sent by your node api?

Comment: i check my angular with `console.log($scope.jurusan)` it say `undefined`

Comment: i tried to console.log below `$scope.jurusan = response.data.jurusan` it show data, but, it's still blank on `ng-repeat`

Comment: try $scope.$digest() after $scope.jurusan = response.data.jurusan

Comment: i got this error `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`

Comment: Then you don't need to add $digest. Basically you have the data in your controller, it is also assigned to `$scope.jurusan`, there would be something small because of which name is not visible. Try to inspect if `value` is being set in options?

Comment: can you show what is the exact `console.log($scope.jurusan);`. Do it after you assign value to it.

Comment: Log looks fine. Try adding `track by $index` to ng-repeat

Comment: like this? `ng-repeat="track by $index`

Comment: ng-repeat="jur in jurusan track by $index  "

Comment: it give the same answer :(

Comment: Check what does this prints in your ng-repeat: {{jur}}